# Scanning double digit from file. Double digits are separating

Tags: c

I am working on a Postfix calculator. I tried `fscanf` and `fgets` both separate double digit numbers. When I scan the file double digits are proceed in the code separately. `25` would be `2` and `5`.

```
char Operand[20];

    fgets(Operand, 20, Filepath);
    for(i = 0; i < strlen(Operand); i++){

        if(Operand[i] == ' ' ){

             continue;
        }

        if( isdigit(Operand[i])){


            PushOperand = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));
            *PushOperand = Operand[i];

            Push(stack, PushOperand );


        }
        else{

            num1 = Pop(stack);
            num2 = Pop(stack);
            number1 = atoi(num1);
            number2 = atoi(num2);
            operator = Operand[i];
            value = GetValue(operator, number1, number2);
            pushVal = &value;
            Push(stack, pushVal);

        }

    }
```

Comment: can you post what the data file looks like

Comment: if your operand is a number (int) you're only allowing for 1 byte (char) when you do the malloc pushoperand is only a char, but operand[i] would be an int. You're losing the top of your int and so only getting the lower part. At least thats what it looks like to me.

Comment: `PushOperand - 48` is amazingly wrong. `PushOperand` is a pointer.

Comment: `strlen(Operand) - 1` - really? (what if the string has length 0? Note: That for-loop has O(n**2).

Comment: added Operand and made changes to code.

Comment: suggest a two state implementation.  1) not in an operand 2) in an operand.  start state:1,  while more characters, if space and state:2, then convert/push operand, set state:1  else if not space set state:2, accumulate character

Comment: in C, do not cast the returned value from malloc (and family of functions) because it is already a void* so can be assigned to any pointer.  Always check the returned value from malloc() and family of functions, to assure the operation was successful

Comment: the operator needs to be verified to be a valid operator +,-,*,/, etc before sending it all to calculate the value

Comment: @user3629249 The function GetValue does that.